# Wordpress rewrite add base prefix to pages only

Tags: wordpress, url-rewriting, permalinks

I have a problem I've encountered when trying to finish a project.

1. I have the current permalink structure set as /%postname%/
2. I made my own function on giving a prefix to posts only so my posts are rewritten as /{prefix}/%postname%/.

My problem is that I want to change the permalink of the **pages** as I did with the posts so my pages will have a prefix like /{prefix}/%pagename%/.

What I tried and didn't work:

1. Re-declare the PAGES post type and set a rewrite slug.
2. Tried adding a custom rewrite rule as a function but it didn't work:

   $rewrite_rules +=  array('mycustomprefix/(.+?)/([0-9]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$' =>'index.php?pagename=$matches[1]',

Is this possible? Are there any developers out there who encountered the same issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For anybody interested, I've fixed my issue in the following manner:

```
function change_author_permalinks() {
global $wp_rewrite;
// Change the value of the author permalink base to whatever you want here
$wp_rewrite->author_base = '';
// Change the value of the page permalink base to whatever you want here
$wp_rewrite->page_structure = 'static/%pagename%';
$wp_rewrite->flush_rules();
}
add_action('init','change_author_permalinks');
```

Hope this helps others as I couldn't find any help for this anywhere. For morer information on what you can change this way, check out http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Rewrite

Answer (score 0):

Have you updated the permalinks structure after adding this rewrite to your functions.php ? It works for me :)

```
add_filter( 'page_rewrite_rules', 'customprefix_page_rewrite_rules' );
function customprefix_page_rewrite_rules( $rewrite_rules )
{
    end( $rewrite_rules );
    $last_pattern = key( $rewrite_rules );
    $last_replacement = array_pop( $rewrite_rules );
    $rewrite_rules +=  array(
        'mycustomprefix/(.+?)/?$' => 'index.php?pagename=$matches[1]',
        $last_pattern => $last_replacement,
    );
    return $rewrite_rules;
}
```

Comment: I think that was my problem, on not flushing the rules. When I've changed to the custom re-write rules, I couldn't access WP-Admin, because I was using Theme My Login and that redirected me to static pages for login/register...Thanks alot!

Comment: Although this works, it doesn't update the Menu Permalinks (using default WP menu). Also, when I use `get_permalink()` it doesn't add the prefix.

Answer (score 0):

I found this solution working for me better... and it's also much cleaner code.

```
add_action( 'init', 'custom_page_rules' );

function custom_page_rules() {
  global $wp_rewrite;
  $wp_rewrite->page_structure = $wp_rewrite->root . 'your-page-prefix/%pagename%'; 
}
```

I found the code here: http://wpforce.com/change-wordpress-page-permalinks/